# execl() does not seem to read from stdin

Tags: c, pipe, exec

I'm trying to reproduce this command in c language:

```
ls | wc > output.txt
```

So, to do that, I wrote the following program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t lsFork, wcFork;
    int tube[2];
    pipe(tube);

    lsFork = fork();
    if(lsFork == 0) // ls command
    {
        close(tube[0]);
        dup2(tube[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(tube[1]);
        if(execl("/usr/bin/ls", "ls", NULL) == -1)
            perror("Cannot execute ls");
    }
    else
    {
        wcFork = fork();
        if(wcFork == 0)  // wc command
        {
            sleep(1);
            int file = open("output.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
            if(file == -1)
                perror("Cannot open output.txt");

            close(tube[1]);
            dup2(tube[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(tube[0]);
            dup2(file, STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(file);

            /*char buffer[BUFSIZ];
            read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, BUFSIZ);
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, BUFSIZ);*/

            if(execl("/usr/bin/wc", "wc", NULL) == -1)
                perror("Cannot execute wc");

            close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        }
        else // parent
        {
            int status;
            waitpid(lsFork, &status, 0);
            waitpid(wcFork, &status, 0);
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But, the program does not exit. According to htop, the wc command is blocking the program. To understand this behaviour, I wrote a piece of code (the lines commented before execl()) and I don't understand what this works and not execl(). Am I forgetting something when calling this function?

Answer (score 1):

The parent process still has the pipe open, so `wc` is waiting around in case the parent decides to write stuff (which `wc` would need to count).

Close both ends of the pipe in the parent too:

```
    else // parent
    {
        int status;
        close(tube[0]); // <---
        close(tube[1]); // <---
        waitpid(lsFork, &status, 0);
        waitpid(wcFork, &status, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't complicate things when you can do it easily..
Try the simpler code below & see if you can understand anything or not.

```
int main(){
    int tube[2];
    int fID;
    pipe(tube);
    if (fork() == 0){
      // this is the child process
      close(tube[0]); // reading end of the pipe
      dup2(tube[1], 1); // stdout ---> pipe writing end
      execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
    }else{
      if (fork() == 0){
        //umask(0022);
        fID = open("sample.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
        close(tube[1]); // writing end of the pipe
        dup2(tube[0], 0);  // stdin ----> pipe reading end
        dup2(fID, 1);
        execlp("wc", "wc", NULL);
      }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

**Note** If the purpose of the code is to solely implement the above mentioned piping, then you don't need to implement any waiting mechanisms. The OS will auto-kill all the zombie child, if any. Moreover `execlp("wc", "wc", NULL);` will auto block the program to end. Hence it will not exit early

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to close the write end of the pipe in the parent too.

Comment: parent is in blocking mode and it is not handling or even touching the pipe.  Closing the write end of the pipe will have no effect & no result.

Comment: pipe(tube);  on the third line of main creates a new pipe in the parent. The child gets a copy of the parent's open fds including the open read and write ends of the pipe. As also mentioned in the other answer the forked process running wc reads from the input fd (in this case the output end of the pipe) until EOF, which it never receives because although the first process in the pipeline terminated not all write ends of the pipe are closed (because it's open in the parent).

-edit-

see man 2 pipe for more info: http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe