# How to cut file name using EXEC + WC command in C

Tags: c, linux, fork, exec, stdout

How can I cut the file name from being printed from the part of my code below?

```
else { /* PROCESS D*/
execl("/bin/wc","wc","-l","temp1.txt", NULL); 
printf("If this message shows up it's an error on process D");
               
}
```

The output is: Found items: 7 temp1.txt

But I'd like it to be

Found items: 7

Answer (score 0):

You pass the content of temp1.txt stdin of the process running wc (see for instance [execl() does not seem to read from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302259/execl-does-not-seem-to-read-from-stdin)), or you run wc via a shell so you can use redirection:

```
execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-c", "wc -l < file1.txt > file2.txt", NULL);
```

Comment: Allan, thanks, as per the post you mentioned I believe ""/bin/bash", "-c", "wc -l < temp1.txt"." would be easier on this case. However, how could I write this in C? I've tried to do it but it's not counting the number of lines

Comment: Yes, just did it "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."
(:

Comment: The accept part it the import piece.  No worries about the upvote, it's more to so you know how to do it as a new user.  Welcome bud!

Comment: Thank you Allan,

Actually reading again what my professor wrote, it's:

wc -l < file1.txt > file2.txt

I can't figure out what the '<' and '>' mean in this case. should I count lines from file1 and print on file2?

Comment: It means wc will read the content from file1.txt and write it's output to file2.txt.

Comment: Thank you mate. Any idea how could I change the code above to do so? 

execl("/bin/wc","wc","-l "<temp1.text","temp2.txt", NULL);

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Use the approach that I gave you, i.e. use a shell.  Updated answer.